# How to prove this inequality $\frac{(\sum_i w_i x_i)}{(\sum_i w_i y_i^2)} \geq \sum_i w_i \frac{x_i}{y_i^2} - C$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This is what I am trying to show $\frac{(\sum_i w_i x_i)}{(\sum_i w_i y_i^2)} \geq \sum_i w_i \frac{x_i}{y_i^2} - C$, where $w_i \geq 1$, $y_i>0$, and $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$. We can assume $x_i>0$ if it makes things easier to prove. $C$ can be constant or another summation, and I not sure what it is(might be zero also).

I've looked at a lot of inequality, including the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, Chebyshev inequality, and others, but I'm not sure how to apply them. I'm not sure where to start. This lemma may not even be provable, in my opinion. Therefore, any assistance is greatly valued.

Comment: According to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4836570/42969, the opposite inequality holds.

Comment: try to start checking a trivial case like considering only one element $i=1$: the left hand size will be $x_1/y_1^2$ since $w_1/w_1 = 1$, and the right hand side will be $w_1x_1/y_1^2$ which is going to be going in the opposite side of your inequality if $w_1>0$ and $C=0$... try other cases to see if what you are asking make sense on trivial cases

Comment: @MarthinR Yes it does. I have modified question a little and I want to explore this kind of inequality now.

Comment: The expression doesn’t seem correct. Consider the case when $w_{1}\to\infty$